# CMake: Header files cannot be opened

Tags: c, cmake, code-composer

I am working to build a Code Composer Studio project using cmake, which is new to me. It builds successfully under Linux but I am struggling to get it to work under Windows. The `cmake` command executes without issue, but `make` fails during the very first C object at the very first `#include` with the error code

```
fatal error: could not open source file "stdbool.h" (no directories in search list)
```

I'm using the libraries included in CCS's compiler (c6000_7.4.15), and that whole folder is included in the CSS project. I include it in cmake as well. In my .cmake file:

```
set (CCS_ROOT ${CCS_ROOT_V6_WIN} CACHE PATH "code composer install directory")
set(CGT_COMPILER_ROOT ${CCS_ROOT}/tools/compiler/c6000_7.4.15 CACHE INTERNAL "DSP Compiler Root")`
```

And in the CMakeLists.txt file:

```
set (COMPILER_INCLUDE ${CGT_COMPILER_ROOT}/include)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ("${COMPILER_INCLUDE}")
```

Why can the header files not be opened when they're linked in the project and CMake can find them just fine?

EDIT: The directory structure had been changed underneath me, so I took the opportunity to add all of the external files directly into the project to make it completely platform-independent. That way, since the project is managed by our Git repository, users won't have to install the CSL or any other programs to build the project. This also means that paths to libraries and header files will never change between revisions and environments.

Unfortunately, this has not solved my problem. The project continues to build in Linux while failing to ind the very first included header file. I also notice that, under Windows, it cannot find my own header files unless I provide a relative path, e.g. `#include "../Common.h"` I can get `make` to find `stdbool.h` if I provide an absolute path to the compiler directory, but that exposes a web of additional broken links between files.

As a side note, the project builds successfully within Code Composer Studio, so I am assuming that this isn't an issue with my specific Windows environment nor with the code within the project itself.

Comment: So the files really exist at that location? If you do a `if(EXISTS ${COMPILER_INCLUDE}/stdbool.h)   message(Found)   endif()` (on 3 lines), does it print?

Comment: @Angew Yes they do. I manually confirmed the location of the files and your code shows that cmake can find them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with `gcc.exe`. I set an environment variable `CC` to the path of a different compiler (in my case a TI compiler) within my build script and that fixed the problem.